# Testing contract with error did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

as I am experimenting with solidity, I have run and deployed my contract locally on a hardhat node:

```
hardhat_addCompilationResult
web3_clientVersion
eth_chainId
eth_accounts
eth_blockNumber
eth_chainId (2)
eth_estimateGas
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_feeHistory
eth_sendTransaction
  Contract deployment: Greeter
  Contract address:    0xcf7ed3acca5a467e9e704c703e8d87f634fb0fc9
  Transaction:         0x783f771362fa427e1a5f4d710735b2138a5b5d82863041f7e18193e9c3c093ae
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  Value:               0 ETH
  Gas used:            497026 of 497026
  Block #4:            0xdecc6521aa4303ea54cc5f21d131309a3d917e1afa01507060ec4689c5f6bfce

  console.log:
    Deploying a Greeter with greeting: Hello, Hardhat!

eth_chainId
eth_getTransactionByHash
eth_chainId
eth_getTransactionReceipt
```

so, it seems that I am out of Gas as above `Gas used:            497026 of 497026`
as I tried to run my hello world contractor, I got this error when tried to consume the contract:

```
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "http://localhost:8545");
            // const id = await web3.eth.net.getId();
            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(MyContract.abi, '0xcf7ed3acca5a467e9e704c703e8d87f634fb0fc9');

            contract.methods.setGreeting("Samee3r").call().then( _ => {
                contract.methods.greet().call().then(result => console.log(result))
            })
```

error:

```
Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
```

so, how to add gas to my testing contract?

**EDIT1**

Contract: `contracts/Greeter.sol`

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Greeter {
    string private greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        console.log("Deploying a Greeter with greeting:", _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        console.log("Changing greeting from '%s' to '%s'", greeting, _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

**EDTI2**

compile and deploy as:

```
npx hardhat run ./scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
```

```
//scripts/deploy.js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

  const Greeter = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
  const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, Hardhat!");

  await greeter.deployed();

  console.log("Greeter deployed to:", greeter.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**EDIT3**

I have deployed the same contract to ropsten testing network, it worked without issue..

Comment: Hello. Give the contract code please.

Comment: Hi, kindly check edits above.